# Is it a syntax error in C++ to end a function inside a class definition with a };?

Tags: c++, function, class, oop

This code was provided to me by my teacher, as an example of functions in a C++ class. It seems strange to me. I've always been used to ending a function with a `}`. I think that only the class definition ends with `};`. Here the function definitions end with `};`. How is a function in a class, besides being public or private, different from a stand alone function? Is this just a quirk or peculiarity of C++?

```
class GenericItem {
public:
   void SetName(string newName) {
      itemName = newName;
   };

   void SetQuantity(int newQty) {
      itemQuantity = newQty;
   };

   void PrintItem() {
      cout << itemName << " " << itemQuantity << endl;
   };

private:
   string itemName;
   int itemQuantity;
};
```

Comment: As I recall C++11 softened the rules about extra semicolons at namespace scope, so that they're now also allowed. The semicolons you show are superfluous,  but do no harm other than (1) possibly causing silly-warnings, and (2) revealing that the coder is not familiar with C++.

Comment: not only class declaration ends with: `};` array initialization ends with `};`  eg: `int a[] = {0};`

Comment: @Raindrop7: Or, indeed, _any_ initialisation: `int a{5};`

Comment: In these examples `;` does not end *initilization*, it ends *declaration*.

Answer (score 18):

It is legal and has always been legal (since C++98), but syntactic meaning of that `;` has changed from C++11 to C++14.

In C++11 (and before) that `;` is allowed, and it is an optional part of member function definition.

> member-declaration:
>       decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> member-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub> ;
>       function-definition ;<sub>opt</sub>
>       ::<sub>opt</sub> nested-name-specifier template<sub>opt</sub> unqualified-id ;
>       using-declaration
>       template-declaration

It is not an empty declaration. (C++11 does not support empty declarations in class scope. Empty declarations are allowed in namespace scope only.) So, in case of C++11 (and before) that extra `;` is indeed just a quirk of language grammar. Why it has always been allowed is not entirely clear to me.

In C++14 (per n4296) this `;` is no longer a part of member function definition. It is a standalone empty declaration, which is legal in class scope since C++14.

> member-declaration:
>       attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> member-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub>;
>       function-definition
>       using-declaration
>       static_assert-declaration
>       template-declaration
>       alias-declaration
>       empty-declaration

This basically means that the following definition is invalid in C++11 (and before), but is valid in C++14

```
class C
{
  void foo() {};;
};
```

(Curiously enough, GCC rejects it in C++14 mode.)

Comment: So I learned something today too, thank you! Uhm, standard quotes?

Comment: `;` matches the first production, though, with both optional parts being absent. (There's a separate rule that bans it that.)

Comment: For reference, the change was introduced by [DR1693](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1693). Since it's a DR, compilers will likely apply it retroactively to their C++11 mode as well. I like the example in there: two semicolons - good, three semicolons - bad.

Answer (score 7):

It's completely valid. The extra semicolon delimits an "empty" declaration.

It's not really a "quirk", since [it's valid after non-member functions too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5abe64771eedf3a3).

It *is* strange to use a `;` when you don't have to, though, so I don't know why your teacher showed it to you this way. It's up to you, but I would generally recommend *not* using the extra `;` (and your compiler, as seen in the warnings it emits for the above code, agrees with me).

Of course, you could simply have tried it to find out.

Comment: Which part of the C++ standard says it's valid?

Comment: @DavidGrayson: At a quick glance, the production _simple-declaration_ allows it. I don't know whether that's _this_ production but search the rest of the grammar for similar rules and you'll find it.

Comment: As far as the grammar goes, an _empty-declaration_ is a _member-declaration_.

Comment: FYI I think `C++11 Standard ch 9.2` covers it marking semicolon as `opt` after a member function definition.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: That answer would apply to C++17, but not to C++14. C++14 does not allow empty declarations in class scope. In C++14 and before only one optional `;` is allowed after in-class function definition and that `;` is part of function definition, not an empty declaration.

Comment: Oops... My draft if C++14 appears to be outdated. The November draft of C++14 is already allowing empty declarations in class scope. So, it is already legal as empty declaration.

Answer (score 2):

';' can be seen as an empty clause that does nothing. To make the code clean, it's not a good way with so many empty clauses that do nothing in the class.

Comment: OK, To keep the code clean, why add so many empty clouses to the class.

Comment: In the answer. Flesh it out. It's very bare and doesn't back itself up, right now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you for your advice, I take it.

Comment: @AnT: Kris has been orbiting around the word "clause"